# Merge MS SQL from 3 records to one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have this SQL

```
SELECT 
      [Item No_]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Property]
      ,[Description]
  FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Item Property] WHERE [Item No_] = '138150'
```

with this result

```
Item No_    Type    Property    Description
138150  LABEL   TEXTLINE1   Spiralledning
138150  LABEL   TEXTLINE2   RJ9 til RJ9
138150  LABEL   TEXTLINE3   2m
```

But, i want a result like this on above specific

```
Item No_ | TextLine1     | TextLine2   | TextLine3
138150   | Spiralledning | RJ0 til RJ9 | 2m
```

It's that possible somehow? (With 3 selects in one string?)

Comment: You want a **Pivot** - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: There are many answers about using Pivot and Unpivot already - now you know the name you should find method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try query like below

```
select [Item No_],[TEXTLINE1],[TEXTLINE2],[TEXTLINE3]
from

(

SELECT 
      [Item No_]
      ,[Property]
      ,[Description]
  FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Item Property] WHERE [Item No_] = '138150'
)
src
pivot
(
max(description) for property in ([TEXTLINE1],[TEXTLINE2],[TEXTLINE3])
)
p
```

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/HWPAYS41172)**</kbd>